# how to Migrate Addons from Github respository to Odoo.sh

Tags: github, odoo, odoo-11, odoo.sh

I have my configuration files uploaded to a repository in GiThub. However I am not sure how to migrate the new addons to my Odoo.sh. I expect i would copy these to the Odoo addon folder but I am not able to see or access this from my Odoo.sh console. HAs anyone done this before and can share how I can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Odoo.sh is a automated deployment system, you don't need to do configuration, addons copying by yourself because Odoo.sh deployment system does that automatically. You have to ensure that your addons are in the root directory of your github repo. Whenever you push your codes in your `production` branch, your `production` instance on Odoo.sh will be build automatically. But you have to perform the Odoo application steps for example "Update addons list", Updating or installing the module once automatic build is complete.

[image: Steps]

Comment: hi Arryph, i am not clear, I have the addons in a Github repository. I did the Update Apps list you showed above and nothing happened.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen, can you please describe?
After updating the apps list, your modules will appear in the list and you have to install it to start using the module in your system

Comment: the addon is in the root of my Github directory. How will using the Update Apps list know to pick the addons from Github. Thats the part I dont understand

Comment: Odoo.sh clones repository and adds the path to `addons_path`, so if your addons are on the root directory of your repo, those addons are discovered by Odoo application on `Update Apps list` action. The cloning of repo is automated system by Odoo.sh.